# Erro ao criar uma nova branch após dar o git clone (sem espaço e ponto)

Tags: git, terminal, branch

Eu errei no comando de git clone pois no final eu esqueci de dar espaço e o ponto, e após dar enter ele clonou e eu segui com as tarefas da aula (curso git/git hub) e a próxima etapa seria dar git branch "listagem" onde surgiu a informação: git branch listagem fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git E tentei forçar com um checkout: git checkout -b "listagem"
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git que também não deu certo, não sei como resolvo.

Comment: basta só entrar na pasta que foi criada (caso tenha realmente clonado) e depois é só seguir a aula. Pode verificar se o diretório que gostaria de clonar foi criado fazendo um `ls` no terminal.

Answer (score -2):

Dá um `git branch` (na pasta do projeto), com esse comando, vai listar todos os branchs do projeto no seu computador. Aí verifica tbm se, ao criar o branch, vc não tenha trocado de posição algumas letras.
Ou então, exclua a pasta do projeto e clona ele novamente.